# How to prevent coming up floating action button (FAB) when clicking a search box in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

How can I prevent a FAB (floating action button) from coming up when I'm clicking on a text field as shown in the following image?
(source code link is available in first comment)

[image: FAB on search box]

Comment: That shouldn't be there. Post you code?

Comment: @scottstoll2017 https://gist.github.com/MeshkaniMohammad/fe22875dbb10623c39aabedb24229ad4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Scaffold has a property to avoid the widgets in it to resize on keyboard pop-up. That would look something like this:

```
Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    body: body,
    appBar: appBar,
);
```

Comment: resizeToAvoidBottomPadding is deprecated, use resizeToAvoidBottomInset instead

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that your TextField won't scroll upward as you type